# characters between two delimiters

Tags: regex

Trying to put a regex expression together that returns the string between _ and _$ (where $ is the end of the string).

input:

```
abc_def_ghi_
```

desired regex outcoume:

```
def_ghi
```

I've tried quite a few combinations such as thsi.

```
((([^_]*){1})[^_]*)_$
```

any help appreciated.

Note: the regex above returns abc_def, and not the desired def_ghi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it's everything between the first `_` and the final `_` (both excluding)?

Then try

```
(?<=_).*(?=_$)
```

(hoping you're not using JavaScript)

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=_)  # Assert that the previous character is a _
.*      # Match any number of characters...
(?=_$)  # ... until right before the final, string-ending _
```

Comment: for me this returns { "abc_, "_" }.

Comment: @sgtz: You need to use the `Regex.Match()` method, not `Regex.Split()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the greedyness of operators to your advantage:

```
^.*?_(.*)_$
```

matches everything from the start (non-greedy), up to an underscore, and from this underscore on to the end of the string, where it expects and underscore, then the end of the string, and captures it in the first match.

```
^    Beginning of string
.*?  Any number of characters, at least 0
_    Anchor-tag, literal underscore
(.*) Any number of characters, greedy
_    Anchor-tag, literal underscore
$    End of string
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using .split(). Using a regular match with the mentioned RegEx should return one captured group, the one you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this within a larger log entry:

```
"threat_name":"PUP.Optional.Wajam"
```

The format enclosed the field name in double quotes then a colon then the value in double quotes.

Here's what I ended up with to avoid punctuation breaking the regex..

```
threat_name["][:]["](?P<signature>.*?)["]
```

(from regex101.com)

- `threat_name` matches the characters threat_name literally (case sensitive)
- `["]` match a single character present in the list below
- `"` a single character in the list " literally (case sensitive)
- `[:]` match a single character present in the list below
- `:` the literal character :
- `["]` match a single character present in the list below
- `"` a single character in the list " literally (case sensitive)
- `(?P<signature>.*?)` Named capturing group signature
- `.*?` matches any character (except newline)
- `Quantifier: *?` Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, 
  expanding as needed [lazy]
- `["]` match a single character present in the list below
- `"` a single character in the list " literally (case sensitive)