# str.match(reg) equivalent for str.split(".") in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a regular expression `reg`, so that for any string `str` the results of `str.split(".")` and `str.match(reg)` are equivalent? If multiline should somehow matter, a solution for a single line would be sufficient.

As an example: Considering the RegExp `/[^\.]+/g`: for the string `"nice.sentance"`, `"nice.sentance".split(".")` gives the same result as `"nice.sentance".match(/[^\.]+/g)` - `["nice", "sentance"]`. However, this is not the case for any string. E.g. for the empty string `""` they would give different results, `"".split(".")` returning `[""]` and `"".match(/[^\.]+/g)` returning `null`, meaning `/[^\.]+/g` is not a solution, as it would need to work for any possible string.

The question comes from a misinterpretation of another question here and left me wondering. I do not have a practical application for it at the moment and am interested because i could not find an answer - it looks like an interesting RegExp problem. It may however be impossible.

Things i have considered:

- Imho it is fairly clear that `reg` needs the global flag, removing capture groups as a possibility
- `/[^\.]+/g` does not match empty parts, e.g. for `""`, `".a"` or `"a..a"`
- `/[^\.]*/g` produces additional empty strings after non-empty matches, because when iteration starts for the next match, it can fit in an empty match. E.g. for `"a"`
- With features not available on javascript [currently](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) (but on other languages), one could repair the previous flaw: `/(?<=^|\.)[^\.]*/g`

My conclusion here would be that real empty matches need to be considered but cannot be differentiated from empty matches between a non-empty match and the following dot or EOL, without "looking behind". This seems a bit vague to count as a proper argument for it being impossible, but maybe is already enough. There might however be a RegExp feature i don't know about, e.g. to advance the index after a match without including the symbol, or something similar to be used as a trick.

Allowing some correction step on the array resulting from `match` makes the problem trivial.

---

I found some related questions, which as expected utilize look-behind or capture groups though:

- [Regular Expression to find a string included between two characters while EXCLUDING the delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454913/regular-expression-to-find-a-string-included-between-two-characters-while-exclud)
- [characters between two delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132627/characters-between-two-delimiters)
- lots more similar to the above

Comment: Adding some sample data which explains the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Why not replace()? Doesn't split() allow regex as a parameter?

Comment: *"e.g. for the empty string "" they would give different results, [""]"* An empty string passed thru split() will result in an array with everything in the string as single chars. So wouldn't the equivalent be: `str.match(/./g)`? BTW, what type of result is:  [""]"*?

Comment: added and changed an example, hopefully it is now a bit more understandable. Searched is a regex while the string operated on varies.

Comment: Where are you going to use this?

Comment: Let alone the problem with empty string or null, it is just impossible with multi character patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see the point but assume you have to apply this in an environment where .split is not available.

Crafting a matching regex that does the same as `.split(".")` or `/\./` requires to account for several cases:

- no input => empty split
- single `.` => two empty splits
- `.` at the beginning => empty split at position 0
- `.` at the end => empty split at the end
- `.` in the middle
- multiple consecutive `.`s => one empty split per `..`

Following this, I came up with the following solution:

```
^(?=\.)[^.]*|[^.]+(?=\.)|(?<=\.)[^.]*$|^$|[^.]+|(?=\.)(?<=\.)
```

Code Sample<sup>*</sup>:

```js
const regex = /^(?=\.)[^.]*|[^.]+(?=\.)|(?<=\.)[^.]*$|^$|[^.]+|(?=\.)(?<=\.)/gm;
const test = `
.
.a
a.
a.a
a..a
.a.
..a..
.a.z
..`;
var a = test.split("\n");
a.forEach(str => {
    console.log(`"${str}"`);
    console.log(str.split("."));
    let m; let matches = [];
    while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
        if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
        }
        matches.push(m[0]);
    }
    console.log(matches);
});
```

The output should be read in triple blocks: input/split/regex-match.
The output on each 2nd and 3rd line should be the same.

Have fun!

<sup>*</sup>**Caveat**: This requires RegExp Lookbehind Assertions: JavaScript Lookbehind assertions are approved by [TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) and are now part of the [ES2018](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) standard.

RegExp Lookbehind Assertions have been implemented in V8 and shipped without flags with [Google Chrome v62](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4545) and in [Node.js v6 behind a flag and v9 without a flag](https://node.green/). The [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665) team is working on it, and for Microsoft Edge, it's an [implementation suggestion](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/34341727-regexp-lookbehind-assertions).

Comment: I'll just take it as "impossible without look-behind or other unavailable features", the current implementation status of look-behind was also interesting. PS: The question itself already discusses a regex with look-behind that is shorter and should work aswell.

Comment: Yes, `/(?<=^|\.)[^\.]*/g` is probably the prefered solution. I just tried to break it down into pieced and test them one by one. More or less every alternation in my pattern addresses one of the test requirements. However, I could not find a solution that worked with ES5.